# Bitmap drawn in a rectangle, now rotate 90 and scale it to the same rectangle

Tags: java, android

I have a Bitmap drawn in a rectangle. I want to rotate the Bitmap to 90 degree and draw the oriented Bitmap in the same rectangle bound, for that I may need to scale it. [image: Normal image appears like this]

[image: Oriented image appears like this]

Above the oriented image is not scaled to fit the rectangle bound of original rectangle (see the first image, the normal one) and also it does remove the lower part of the image. Below is code snippet. Any suggestion ?

```
sourceImageRect.left = 0;
sourceImageRect.top = 0;
sourceImageRect.right = bmp.getWidth();
sourceImageRect.bottom = bmp.getHeight();

destImageRect.top = destTop;
destImageRect.left = destLeft;
destImageRect.right = destLeft + destWidth;
destImageRect.bottom = destTop + destHeight;

canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);

canvas.rotate(90, (destLeft + (destWidth / 2)),
    (destTop + (destHeight / 2)));

canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, sourceImageRect, destImageRect, null);

canvas.restore();
```

[image: This is the output image I need]

Last image is exact required output I need.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/fK2CzTCz

Comment: pastebin code looks like full screen orientation, can be used in my case with some effort. +1 for giving pointer.

Comment: what full screen orientation? what you mean? did you run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of @pskink pastebin reference, following way I resolved and it's working code,

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap bmpRotated =  Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpSource, 0, 0, bmpSource.getWidth(), bmpSource.getHeight(), matrix, true);


sourceImageRect.left = 0;
sourceImageRect.top = 0;
sourceImageRect.right = bmpRotated.getWidth();
sourceImageRect.bottom = bmpRotated.getHeight();

destImageRect.top = destTop;
destImageRect.left = destLeft;
destImageRect.right = destLeft + destWidth;
destImageRect.bottom = destTop + destHeight;

canvas.drawBitmap(bmpRotated, sourceImageRect, destImageRect, null);
```

However, I managed to create Bitmap outside of OnDraw()

Comment: you dont need any extra  `Bitmap bmpRotated` - see my code

Answer (score 0):

I writed a tool java class named [`ImageScaleUtil.java`](https://github.com/jiarWang/AndroidView/blob/master/M0802/app/src/main/java/com/example/milka/m0802/Camera/Util/ImageScaleUtil.java) several days ago. Helping you can get some useful information on it.

You can use it, like this:

```java

```
Bitmap targetBitmap = ImageScaleUtil.getScaleBitmap(Bitmap sourceBitmap, int reqWidth, int reqHeight);
```

```